# how to select column name along with with aggregate function applied on it

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to get column name along with aggregate function applied on it like below.

***select column_name, sum(column_name) from table;***

Comment: You have to use `group by` on that column

Comment: You can easily google out this question. You don't need to put this here. There are links that can answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you want?

```
select column_name, sum(column_name) group by column_name from table;
```

Comment: The way the columns are to be fetched is bit complicated. I'm storing column names of table B in table A and executing query to pull column name and it's actual sum from table B. 

Let's say table A, table B has below structures.

Comment: table A

+------+------+
| id   | name |
+------+------+
|  1   | col1 |  
|  2   | col2 | 
|  3   | col3 |  
+------+------+

table B

+------+--------+------+
| col1 |  col2  | col3 | 
+------+--------+------+
|  1   |   22   |  1   | 
|  1   |   22   |  2   |
+------+--------+------+

Tried executing the query "select a.name, sum(a.name) from A a, B b". 
Expecting the output in the below format.

+---------+------------+
| a.name  |sum(a.name) |
+-------  +---------+
|  col1   |   2       |
|  col2   |   44     |
|  col3   |   3       |
+---------+--------+

Comment: But the actual output returns is below.

+---------+-------------+
| a.name  |  sum(a.name)|
+---------+-------------+
|  col1   |   0         |
|  col2   |   0         |
|  col3   |   0         |
+---------+-------------+

Any help would be highly appreciated and thanks in advance.